# Convert String Tokenizer

Tags: c#, c++

Can someone please help me in converting the StrTok code to C# from C++?

```
strFileName = StringFunctions.StrTok(strFileToCopy, "\\");
strFileName = StringFunctions.StrTok(null, "\0");
```

Tried Code:

```
string strFileName = ""; 

string[] FileNames = Regex.Split(strFileToCopy, "\\");
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? If you haven't tried anything, [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) might be a good starting point

Comment: Ok so i have used the Split for the StrTok .. Is this the right way ???                  string strFileName = "";
string[] FileNames = Regex.Split(strFileToCopy, "\\");

Comment: What was wrong with `Split` ?

Comment: I wanted to understand how the StrTok can be used in a better way ? with the above code ?

Comment: Use string split not regex

Comment: If you are really getting a file name, then use [`Path.GetFileName(…)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @shashank what are you trying to do, what does `strtok` have to do with it and why use `Regex.Split` instead of `String.Split` or `Path.GetFileName()` ? Just because one language provides some function doesn't mean another language will have to provide the *same* function. It may have a different name or there may be far better functions for the job

Comment: Hi, is there anything you're still unsure about with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description and example of `StrTok` here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/, it seems *roughly equivalent to the [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of `string`:

```
var str = "- This, a sample string.";
var pch = str.Split(" ,.-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var result in pch)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This outputs:

> This
>
> a
>
> sample
>
> string

which matches the sample from the linked strtok page.

*I think the difference is that to get all of the entries with strtok, you have to call it repeatedly, passing `NULL` for subsequent calls, whereas C#'s `Split` simply returns an array of tokens.

---

As others have suggested in the comments, if you simply want to obtain the filename, you should use `Path.GetFileName` instead (you'll need to add `using System.IO;`):

```
string str = @"c:\users\john\desktop\test.txt";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(str));
```

Outputs:

> test.txt

Answer (score -1):

You can use the stringstream from std

```cpp
std::istringstream ss("This is the line to tokenize");
std::string token;

while(std::getline(ss, token, ' '))
    std::cout << "line: " << token << "\n";

// Out:
/*
This
is
the
line
to
tokenize
*/
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "how do I convert this strtok code to c#"!